# screen resolution dependent image source

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am developing a Windows 8 metro (yeah!) app. How do i provide a screen resolution dependent image source ?

As per [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx) guidelines, we can achieve it using image naming convention too.

I have an image control as show below.

```
<Image Source="Assets/test.jpeg"/>
```

I also have test.scale-100.jpg, test.scale-140.jpg & test.scale-180.jpg images in asset folder. Each image having different icon color to identify which image is loaded.

If i run the app in simulator and change screen resolutions, i still see test.scale-100.jpg for any resolution. Why is this happening ? In which case will the OS load test.scale-140.jpg or test.scale-180.jpg image ?

**EDIT:** I got it working. Once your app starts in simulator, close it by pressing home buton & uninstall it. In VS, right click on Project and click on Deploy. App should be now deployed to simulator. Change the resolution and start the app. You should now see correct image loaded by OS. Rinse and repeat to test other resolutions.

Comment: re. your edit - You're doing way more than you need to there. You just need to close the app, and re-launch it. Not that pressing the Windows key (as per your comment to my answer) won't close the app, but just gives focus to the start screen. To close your app, either press Alt-F4, or swipe down from the top of the screen to the bottom. Once you have closed the app properly, restarting it in a different simulator resolution will be enough to reflect the change.

Answer (score 1):

The scaling is automatic.  If your images are correctly named, and you change resolution in the simulator **you must restart the app to see scaled images**.  It doesn't happen on the fly, IIRC.

Comment: So here is what i am doing. Press F5 from VS. It launches the Simulator at 10.6" 1024x768 resolution. App is started & I see test.scale-100.jpg as expected. 
Next, I close app by pressing HOME button. Change screen resolution of simulator to 27" Inch and start the app. I still see the same test.scale-100.jpg instead of test.scale-140.jpg or test.scale-180.jpg

Answer (score 0):

1. Finally got it working. close the app and uninstall it from
   simulator.
2. In VS, right click the project and click deploy.
3. Change to desired screen resolution and start the app. OS should not pick proper image as per resolution.
4. Rinse and repeat same to test images on various resolutions.

Comment: You're doing way more than you need to there.  You just need to close the app, and re-launch it.  Not that pressing the Windows key (as per your comment to my answer) won't close the app, but just gives focus to the start screen.  To close your app, either press Alt-F4, or swipe down from the top of the screen to the bottom.  Once you have closed the app properly, restarting it in a different simulator resolution will be enough to reflect the change.

Comment: I will check this once i reach home. Will also update the answer accordingly. Thanks for the tip.